# slash(\) gets prepend when using PropertiesConfiguration setProperty

Tags: java, properties-file

I have key value pair **jndi.DataSource**=**jdbc/MC** in .properties file

My following code prepend slash ex. **jndi.DataSource**=**jdbc\ /MC**

```
    PropertiesConfiguration configProp = new PropertiesConfiguration(prop.properties);  
    configProp.setProperty(propertyKeyToBeChanged, propertyValue);  
    configProp.save();
```

How can I stop it.

Comment: I strongly suspect you actually have a space in the property value, but even then it's not entirely clear why it would be escaped. It doesn't help that we don't know what the `PropertiesConfiguration` type is. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration; I am using apache commons configuration to edit Property file

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet for your input

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug. I was using commons-lang-2.4.jar. Use commons-lang-2.6.jar to solve the problem.